# how do I extract a token from a observable response when using HttpClient?

Tags: typescript, httpclient, angular7

How do I extract a token from a callback response when I am using HttpClient?

I already tried to parse the Object to json, but parse fails because it detects the token in the Object:

```
JSON.parse(data.toString())
```

gives this error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse ()

```
this.auth.getObject(this.form.value).subscribe(
      data=>{
        localStorage.setItem("token",data.token);
```

I am expecting to get the token from the callback response, but since it is an Object when using HttpClient, it is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Can you post the json file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your response object have token parameter, since **HttpClient** response is already a JSON object but we need to store this in a Object first, do some changes in your subscription.

```
 this.auth.getObject(this.form.value).subscribe(
      response => {
       let data: any = response; 
       localStorage.setItem("token",data.token);
 })
```

I hope this will solve your issue :)